# Count() on joins for pagination, getting additional rows

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I have this problem that when i run this one.

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customers 
        RIGHT JOIN orders on customers.serial=orders.serial 
        RIGHT JOIN order_detail on orders.serial=order_detail.orderid 
        LEFT JOIN inventory on order_detail.productid=inventory.prod_id");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records
```

it shows additional pages even if it's blank. i've tried on other tables that doesnt require me to join and it works on them. But with this one, it does not work perfectly.

How do i fix my count function?

here is my original query before tweaking the pagination codes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.order_status,customers.serial,customers.name,customers.address,customers.phone,customers.email,customers.payment,customers.carrier,customers.tracking_no, orders.date, order_detail.productid, order_detail.quantity, order_detail.price, inventory.prod_name 
        FROM customers 
        RIGHT JOIN orders on customers.serial=orders.serial 
        RIGHT JOIN order_detail on orders.serial=order_detail.orderid 
        LEFT JOIN inventory on order_detail.productid=inventory.prod_id
        GROUP BY orders.date, order_detail.orderid
        ORDER BY order_detail.orderid DESC";
```

Comment: I am totally befuddles on your question.  Your first query has a `count(*)` and no `group by`, so it always returns one row.  Hence, there are no "additional rows".  The second has a `group by`, so it doesn't seem particularly related to the first.  Plus, you have this strange mixture of outer joins, which makes the query quite hard to disentangle.

Comment: My first query was meant to be for a single table, ive downloaded a demo from the internet which i tweaked and had problems with joined tables, thus my second query.  @GordonLinoff

Comment: I wonder if you get the desired results from the query. Using right joins is not recomended, so using both left and right joins can only result in a mess

Comment: @Gervs my query works fine. hehe.

Answer (score 0):

To much to put in a comment:

There are three ways to get the total records for use with pagination.

1. Execute the query without the limit and get the number of records in the resultset. It maybe obvious that this isn't the way to go.
2. Execute the query with the limit and use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.
3. Replace the colums in the SELECT clause with COUNT(1) and fetch the (single) row.

In many situations  the third is the best choice, however sometimes the second can out perform the third.

Finally, see this predicates

- A product which isn't in inventory can't be ordered
- An order can't be submitted by non-customers

I think inner joins are sufficient